# how to Identify which of Snowflake's partner tools/solutions (BI, ETL, etc.) are consuming the most credits

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do we find which partner tools is consuming most credits in snowflake.

I can get most credits results for drivers(JDBC,ODBC),but i need to find for tools like power bi etc.

Answer (score 0):

Credits are consumed for a duration warehouse is active, not by any drivers or tools.
More details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#virtual-warehouse-credit-usage

Users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role can use the Snowflake web interface or SQL to view monthly and daily credit usage for all the warehouses in your account.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#viewing-warehouse-credit-usage-for-your-account

Comment: it seems like there is no way we can this,any one tried ?

Comment: you may utilize quer_tag that can be set at the user session-level. ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG='POWERBI'; For all the queries executed from power bi tool.